# bash Grep multiple lines for "BID_1:****" and save to "****_name" where **** are numbers

Tags: bash, ubuntu, grep

as in the title - I have a file with multiple lines, where each contains string `BID_1:****`. `****` are different numbers. For example:

```
string1 string2 BID_1:1111 string3
string1 string2 BID_1:2222 string3
string1 string2 BID_1:3333 string3
string1 string2 BID_1:4444 string3
string1 string2 BID_1:5555 string3
```

Is there a chance by using one command to grep `BID_1:1111` and save to `1111_name`, `BID_1:2222` and save to `2222_name`, ..., `BID_1:5555` and save to `5555_name` etc.? I mean something like

```
grep "BID_1:****" filename > ****_filename2
```

If there is not, how can I do it so as not to do it manually, grep by grep?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Cannot edit. It should start with:
"as in the title - I have a file with multiple lines, where each contains string BID_1:****. 
**** are different numbers. For example:"

Answer (score 5):

I think this would be easier using awk. Like:

```
awk '{
  file = substr($3, 7) "_suffix"
  print > file
  # close(file)
}' file
```

The magical 7 is the length of the prefix `BID_1:` plus 1, `3` is the number of field that string appears as. You may need to uncomment `close(file)` depending on the size of your actual input and the awk version you have.

Answer (score 2):

A `bash` shell solution with `grep`

```
grep "BID_1:****" file.txt | while read -ra line; do echo "${line[@]}" > "${line[2]#*:}_name"; done
```

It will be very slow on a large set of data/files.

Answer (score 2):

If you can make use of gnu awk, you can use a pattern with a capture group and use the value of the group in the filename.

- `\<` A word boundary
- `BID_1:` Match literally
- `([0-9]+)` Capture **group 1** (denoted by `m[1]` in the code) match 1+ digits
- `\>` A word boundary

Using a mechanism like in the answer of @[oguz ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10248678/oguz-ismail) for the filename:

```
awk '
match($0, /\<BID_1:([0-9]+)\>/, m) {
  file = m[1] "_name"
  print > file
}' filename
```

If the data is always the 3rd field, you can use `$3` instead of `$0`